# GIT - Setting up for multiple developers on 1 machine

Tags: git

I am a complete beginner to GIT and I am looking at setting up a multi user git environment in our office.

We have a central (local) linux box that I want to have git on and 4 developers using it. This server is running a LAMP stack also.

I'm pretty sure I need to have 1 master repository and then each user pulls from it in to their own user accounts, then work on it and then commit back to the master.

But how do I do this!?

I thought I would need to setup users in GIT then each dev uses their own login. But I can't find any info on that. Does each dev need to have a user account on the server and login with that (samba)? Will GIT use and recognise their logins?
Also the local server has its web root set so how would each dev be able to see their own work in the browser? Would each users local copy need to be in the www root? e.g.:

```
/www
    /dev1
        /site1
    /dev2
        /site1
    /dev3
        /site1
    /dev4
        /site1
```

Any pointers very much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is (at least from my point of view):

Create a "bare" repository. You can call it your central repository...

```
create a folder which will containing the repository (has to be group writable)
init the git repository in that folder (git init --bare --shared)
```

Make sure that all users have the same primary grou in linux. After this, users can use ssh (create key pairs to simplify the login for your users) to login and clone the repository...

[git init --bare --shared](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init)

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) Is the repository you mention creating bare the "Main" repository? (i.e.: All devs will pull from it?)

Comment: Yes, the difference to a normal repository is, that a bare one has no "workspace"...

Comment: ... and yes, all developer can (in central approach should) use this.